# Android | Kotlin | How to get a text using a variable ID within getString()

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried a lot of combinations, but somehow I don't get it.

The id for the text I want to show is generated.

**I need to write a variable here instead of a concrete id**.

So not:

```
getString(R.string.id_1)
```

But something like:

```
var myId = ... 
getString(R.string."$myId")
```

Do you know what I mean? What ever I tried I got an error that only an Int.

How would you solve this in Kotlin?

Comment: i am not getting your point.

Comment: as far as i know its not possible that you can put dynamic name to access string resource

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple languages/localization?

Comment: getString needs Resource ID, You can't pass a String into that parameter, It needs Integer

Comment: To get the values from the Textview we have to use this method
 val str = textView.text.toString()

Comment: val string: String = getString(R.string.your_string_id)

Comment: var  a = resources.getString(R.string.app_name);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code, it will work for you:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.getString(name: String): String {
   return resources.getString(resources.getIdentifier(name, "string", packageName))
}

Usage: val resource = getString($resourceName);
```

Comment: maybe it'll be better as extension function?

Comment: @StefanGolubović thank for the suggestion buddy, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to access string resource dynamically than you have to create pattern something like below

string.xml

```
<string name="abc">Hello</string>
<string name="abc1">Hello1</string>
<string name="abc2">Hello2</string>
<string name="abc3">Hello3</string>
```

java code

```
getString(R.string.abc+<index>)
```

this is just an idea, i haven't tried it.
Let me know whether it works or fail.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Do you thing it will help her ? It's an integer parameter, We need  to pass an integer value (Resource ID). How can we concatenate an integer like this ?

Comment: IDE won't throw error for it that is for sure but as i mentioned i haven't tried it and its just an idea

Comment: Dear readers and visitors do not down vote without trying it your self.

Comment: I tried it and then I get these errors "expecting an element" and "unresolved reference" for the variable name. Any idea?